# Slicing a list starting from given index and jumping/stepping it with some integer

Tags: python, list

I have the general idea of how to do this in php, but I am new to Python and not sure how to do it.

I am trying to implement a function that **returns a `list` containing every second element of every three elements of the list**.

For example, if my list is:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12]
```

I would like the function to return:

```
[2,5,8,11]
```

---

In General I am thinking we will slice the total values of the list in 3 equal parts then get every second element?

```
[1, 2, 3,| 4, 5, 6,| 7, 8, 9,| 10,11,12] => [2,5,8,11]
```

I have tried python split function but it doesn't work on list. I would also has to be consider total length of the list. It might be an even number.

Answer (score 19):

All you need is *list slicing* starting from index `1` and then you need to jump by `3` indexes:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> my_list[1::3]
[2, 5, 8, 11]
```

General syntax of *list slicing* is `your_list[start:end:jump]` where:

- **`start`**: is the starting index for slicing the list. Empty value means start of the list i.e. index `0`
- **`end`**: is the index till which you want to slice the list. Empty value means end of the list
- **`jump`**: is used to jump the elements from `start` such that you'll get values in the order `start`, `start+jump`, `start+2*jump`, so on till your list reaches `end`. Empty value means `1`

As mentioned by Mr. [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85) in comment, for large lists one should prefer [**`itertools.islice`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) which returns iterator object and could be used in this case as:

```
from itertools import islice  # import islice

islice(my_list, 1, None, 3)
```

Comment: If you have a large list, and want to iterate over each element at a time, then `itertools.islice` would work nicely. `itertools.islice(lst, 1, None, 3)`

Comment: If you had used their variable name, then you'd now have 10 upvotes for 10 characters :-) (very surprising, btw... I guess this somehow isn't well-known?)