# Python: How to get the 2nd and 4th element of a list, then every 4th element of each after?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a web-scraped list that contains each players number, name, hometown, and position in one continuous list.

`my_list = [1, Bob, Austin, Pitcher, 2, Jim, New York, Catcher, 3, Will, Kansas, Left Field, ...]`

I need to be able to access just the name and position of each player in the list.

Ex: `result_list = [Bob, Pitcher, Jim, Catcher, Will, Left Field]`

I have tried using an if statement with a count nested in a for loop for each element in 'my_list' but I can't seem to get it.

Here is the full code, the only difference is I am also using a for loop for each team in the conference in order to get the right 'team' variable for my web scraping and I need the 2nd element, the 6th element, and each 7th element of each after that (my end goal is to add each players name and position to a NEW player model):

```
def league(request, league_id, league_title):
```

south_conf = ['Chemeketa','Clackamas','Clark','Lane','Linn-Benton','Mt Hood','SW Oregon','Umpqua']
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT
session.headers['Accept-Language'] = LANGUAGE
session.headers['Content-Language'] = LANGUAGE

```
for team in south_conf:
    team = str(team)
    team = team.lower()
    team = team.replace(' ','')
    team = team.replace('-','')
    team = team.replace('sworegon', 'southwesternoregon')
    team_html_content = session.get(f'https://nwacsports.com/sports/bsb/2021-22/teams/{team}?view=roster').text
    team_soup = BeautifulSoup(team_html_content, 'html.parser')
    team_rows = team_soup.find_all('table')
    team_rows = team_rows[3]
    count = 0
    for ele in team_rows.find_all('td')[1::]:
        if count % 7 == 0:
            obj = Player()
            obj.name = str(ele.text)
            obj.team = team
            obj.save()
            print(ele.text)
            
            count += 1
        else:
            count += 1


return render(request, 'league/league.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote for the for loop? Sounds like that would be a fine solution

Comment: I'll edit my post to include the code. It is a Django application in views.py but the logic should be the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slicing a list starting from given index and jumping/stepping it with some integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351334/slicing-a-list-starting-from-given-index-and-jumping-stepping-it-with-some-integ)

Comment: It's close, but I am basically needing to do that skipping for the first two values independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
my_list[1::2]
```

where the `1` means to start at index `1` (which is `Bob`) and the `2` gives every second element after that (`Pitcher`, `Jim`, etc.)

EDIT:

I do not understand what it is you want to do. But I suggest you work with a numpy array (which makes slicing somewhat easier):

```
my_array = np.array(my_list).reshape(3, 4)
```

Now you can get all information from player i by doing `my_array[i,:]`. Or get all names by doing `my_array[:,1]`.

Another option is to use `pandas` to create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(my_list).reshape(3, 4), columns=['nr', 'Name', 'City', 'Position'])
```

Now you can get all information from player i by doing `df.iloc[i]`. Or get all names by doing `df.Name`.

I hope this provides enough information to continue your work :D

Comment: Sorry in advance for my poor question asking skills, this is my first question of here. That is close to what I need but my situation is a little more involved, I need the 'name' and 'position' (element '1' and '3') then create a new player model for that, then I need the next set of 'name' and 'position' (element '5' and '7', '4' elements after each).